# RE на 7 тесте. ООП

Tags: python

Такое условие:
Вас попросили написать 2 класса, *CustomList* и *CustomDict*, оба эти класса имеют атрибут *data*, в котором хранится ссылка на список или словарь соответственно. В конструкторе класса передается список или словарь, также атрибут *data* можно изменять в процессе работы с классами, то есть:

```
my_list = CustomList([1, 2, 3])  
my_list.data = [1, 2]
```

Оба эти класса имеют одни и те же свойства:

- *size* - размер списка или словаря,
- *max_value* - максимальный элемент списка или максимальный ключ словаря
- *min_value* - минимальный элемент списка или минимальный ключ словаря

Также печать экземпляров обоих классов должна возвращать строку в формате:

```
My CustomList data [1, 2, 3] 
My CustomDict data {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
```

Общие свойства и методы этих двух классов должны реализованы в классе *CommonProperties*, от которого
будут наследоваться классы *CustomList* и *CustomDict*.

*max_value* и *min_value* для словаря нужно считать не только по ключам, но и по значениям. В случае, если вы пытаетесь сравнить несравнимые объекты, нужно попытаться посчитать *max_value* и *min_value* только по ключам, если и это невалидно, нужно выкинуть исключение *TypeError*. Для этого функционала
реализуйте класс *DictProperties*, от которого будет наследоваться класс *CustomDict*.

Если же вы пытаетесь сравнить несравнимые для списка объекты (например, строки и числа), нужно выкинуть исключение *TypeError*.

```
import sys


class CommonProperties():

    def __init__(self, nums):
        self.nums = nums

    @property
    def size(self):
        return str(len(self.nums))
  
    @property
    def min_value(self):
        if isinstance(self, CustomList):
            return min(self.nums)
        else:
            return DictProperties.find_min(self)

    @property
    def max_value(self):
        if isinstance(self, CustomList):
            return max(self.nums)
        else:
            return DictProperties.find_max(self)


class CustomList (CommonProperties):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'My CustomList data ' + str(self.nums)

    @property
    def data(self):
        return str(self.nums)

    @data.setter
    def data(self, nums):
        self.nums = nums


class DictProperties(CommonProperties):
    def find_max(self):
        skey, svalue = set(), set()
        lkey, lvalue = [], []
        for k, v in self.nums.items():
            skey.add(type(k))
            svalue.add(type(k))
            lkey.append(k)
            lvalue.append(v)
        if len(skey) == 1 and len(svalue) == 1:
            return max(max(lkey, lvalue))
        elif len(skey) == 1:
            return max(lkey)
        elif len(svalue) == 1:
            return max(lvalue)
        else:
            raise TypeError

    def find_min(self):
        skey, svalue = set(), set()
        lkey, lvalue = [], []
        for k, v in self.nums.items():
            skey.add(type(k))
            svalue.add(type(k))
            lkey.append(k)
            lvalue.append(v)
        if len(skey) == 1 and len(svalue) == 1:
            return min(min(lkey, lvalue))
        elif len(skey) == 1:
            return min(lkey)
        elif len(svalue) == 1:
            return min(lvalue)
        else:
            raise TypeError


class CustomDict(DictProperties):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'My CustomDict data ' + str(self.nums)

    @property
    def data(self):
        return str(self.nums)

    @data.setter
    def data(self, nums):
        self.nums = nums
exec(sys.stdin.read())
```

Еще в этом коде явно вызываю метод класса *DictProperties*  таким образом `DictProperties.find_max(self)`.  Хотя должно быть так просто `find_max()`. Понимаю, что нужно наследовать какой то класс. пробовал, не получается)) Может Вы поможете?

Comment: @GrAnd Можете помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось, что ни в классе `CustomDict`, ни в `CustomList` даже имплементировать нечего. :)

Смотрите:

- *data* хранится в базовом классе `CommonProperties`, т.к. она есть и у `CustomList` и у `CustomDict`.
- `find_min`/`find_max` тоже можно реализовать в базовом классе. Для списка их переопределять не надо, они и так работать будут. Для словаря они будут работать наполовину (искать только по ключам), так что там придётся переопределять.
- `__repr__` (формат вывода на печать) тоже можно переопределить в базовом классе, т.к. имя класса можно достать из *self*.
- Для `CustomDict` переопределяем `find_min`/`find_max`. Для поиска по ключам используется аналогичная функция предка (базового класса), хотя можно и напрямую *min/max* вызвать (но через вызов метода предка интереснее же ;). Ну и аккуратно обрабатываем *exceptions* (даже самому их генерировать нет надобности, функции *min/max* и так их генерят).

```py
class CommonProperties():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'My {self.__class__.__name__} data {self.data}'

    @property
    def size(self):
        return len(self.data)
  
    def find_min(self):
        return min(self.data)

    @property
    def min_value(self):
        return self.find_min()

    def find_max(self):
        return max(self.data)

    @property
    def max_value(self):
        return self.find_max()


class CustomList (CommonProperties):
    pass


class DictProperties(CommonProperties):
    def find_max(self):
        max_key = super().find_max()
        try:
            max_value = max(self.data.values())
            return max(max_key, max_value)
        except TypeError:
            return max_key

    def find_min(self):
        min_key = super().find_min()
        try:
            min_value = min(self.data.values())
            return min(min_key, min_value)
        except TypeError:
            return min_key


class CustomDict(DictProperties):
    pass

l = CustomList([1,3,6,99,-18.5,-3])
print(l, f"size={l.size}  min={l.min_value}  max={l.max_value}")
# l.data = [7, 15, "a", True]   # для того чтобы вызвать TypeError exception
# print(l, f"size={l.size}  min={l.min_value}  max={l.max_value}")

d = CustomDict({-3:33, 15:321})
print(d, f"size={d.size}  min={d.min_value}  max={d.max_value}")
d.data = {"a":2, "b":1}
print(d, f"size={d.size}  min={d.min_value}  max={d.max_value}")
d.data = {"a":2, 7:"z"}   # для того чтобы вызвать TypeError exception
print(d, f"size={d.size}  min={d.min_value}  max={d.max_value}")
```

```js
My CustomList data [1, 3, 6, 99, -18.5, -3] size=6  min=-18.5  max=99
My CustomDict data {-3: 33, 15: 321} size=2  min=-3  max=321
My CustomDict data {'a': 2, 'b': 1} size=2  min=a  max=b
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```